# Why does this dojo code produce an 'Unexpected end of input'?

Tags: ajax, dojo

I am writing a simple dojo program to upload files to a server. But everytime I select the file I get an error saying unexpected end of input.

```
dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");
        //dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash");
var f1 = new dojox.form.Uploader({
        url:"/IFixBuildWeb/UploadHandlerServlet/Upload"
        ,multiple:false
        ,label:"selectBtn"
        ,uploadOnSelect: true
        }, "selectBtn");
f1.startup();
```

It allows me to select the files however in chrome javascript console I get an error saying unexpected end of input.

I have not created a form but have just made a html table and the uploader is inside of that. What is wrong with the above code or is it necessary to make a form and set its enctype to multiform/data?

I have an event handler for onComplete which is not being triggered. I read on the dojo site that this is usually because of a mismatch between the type of plugin used and the type of data which is expected to be returned from the server side. But I am not sure how to check/confirm this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need HTML form for HTML5 plugin. If you see source code of HTML5.js you'll see 
...
    postCreate: function(){
        this.connectForm();
...
and connectForm method in Base.js use HTML form.

Flash and IFrame - maybe not need.

Comment: I used the HTML5 plugin but I am not sure about the form. I think in the documentation it says that using a form is optional. The upload itself is happening( I can see the file on the server) but on the client side I get this error and the onComplete event is not being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening just in IE(which falls back to Flash upload mode) or is it in all the browsers?